# How to get current time in English in Android?

Tags: android, datetime

I want to get the current time specifically in English to save it in a Database. To get the current time, I use the function

```java
private String get_current_Time() {
    String CURRENT_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_hh_mm_ss_a_MMMM_MMM_EEEE_EE";
    return (String) DateFormat.format(CURRENT_TIME_FORMAT, Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

But when I set the Locale to different language, it gives me the current time in that language. For example if I set

```java
conf.setLocale(new Locale("mr"));
```

it gives me the date in Marathi. I specifically want it in English. How to do this?

And also how to change the language of Date once it is saved. I mean if I have saved date in English and while display I want that date to be shown in some other language, how to do it?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormate` with `Locale`.

Comment: If you already know how to change the language, what part of requesting the English language is difficult? [`Locale.ENGLISH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#ENGLISH), [`Locale.UK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#UK), [`Locale.US`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#US). Any of those would work, don't you thing?

Comment: @ADM thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As ADM suggested. new function that worked

```
 public String get_current_Time() {
 String CURRENT_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_hh_mm_ss_a_MMMM_MMM_EEEE_EE";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(CURRENT_TIME_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);
        return dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    }
```

So now it always returns Date  in English

Comment: Need to add 'Locale.ENGLISH' parameter to SimpleDateFormat object

Answer (score -1):

This should fix your issue! Try any of these
[here is a simple tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/)

For `java.util.Date`, just create a new `Date()`

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
log.d(dateFormat.format(date)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

For `java.util.Calendar`, uses `Calendar.getInstance()`

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
log.d(dateFormat.format(cal)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

For `java.time.LocalDateTime`, uses `LocalDateTime.now()`

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
log.d(dtf.format(now)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

For `java.time.LocalDate`, uses `LocalDate.now()`

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
log.d(dtf.format(localDate)); //2016/11/16
```